# JSF2: How to send a GET request from a button submitting input values?

Tags: java, jsf-2, get, httprequest

Is this possible to pass inputs in a GET request from a JSF button?

For example for the following elements, I want button to redirect user to something like: `search-page.xhtml?input=userSearchText`, so that my search page is bookmarkable.

```
<h:inputText value="#{bean.searchText}"/>
<h:button outcome="search" />
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's not possible by alone a `<h:button>`. It's really a simple redirect-button, not a form submit button.

Since you do not need to set anything in the bean by POST, you can use a normal HTML GET `<form>` and replace the JSF components by their normal HTML representation so that you have fine grained control over the input names:

```html
<form action="search-page.xhtml">
    <input name="input" value="#{bean.searchText}" />
    <input type="submit" />
</form>
```

The only disadvantage is that you can't utilize JSF implicit navigation by `outcome`. But that shouldn't be a major showstopper imo.

Comment: Is this possible that the button submits to a special method in a JSF bean? How can I detect form submission on bean side.

Comment: Use `<f:metadata><f:viewParam/><f:event/></f:metadata>` on the target view.